# How to open/close a angular-material menu

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I recently started using angular-material and am struggling/unsure about opening/closing a mat-menu...  I see in the examples on the angular-material documentation site that they assign an id to the menu and then apply a directive to the button that is used to toggle the menu. e.g. `[matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"`

How can I go about writing a directive that does that?  I'm not sure how to pass a reference to a specific menu to a directive that then calls the `toggle()` method on the DOM element with that id?

The following code produces the errors:

> Can't bind to 'matMenuTriggerFor' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.

There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "matMenu".
My code:

```
<li>
    <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="stockSystemMenu">
        <mat-icon class="sn-item">
            <i class="material-icons">archive</i>
        </mat-icon>
    </button>
    <span class="sn-item" (click)="toggleMenu(stockSystemMenu)">Stok System</span>

    <mat-menu #stockSystemMenu="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item>
            <mat-icon>
                <i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i>
            </mat-icon>
        <span>Service 1</span>
        </button>
    </mat-menu>
</li>
```

Comment: your code? what is that you have tried?

Comment: @Aravind i'm not sure at all about how to start this.  I somehow need to pass a reference of a dom element's ID to this directive which then should call the toggle() function of that dom element?

Comment: if you can elaborate I will help you to fix this!

Comment: @Aravind i'm just not sure at all of how to go about doing this...  i've never had to write a directive that does anything like this so finding it hard to figure out the flow of the entire process.  If you take a look at Aravind under examples they use a directive [matMenuTriggerFor] on a button that opens a menu, unfortunately they didn't add the directive code to the example so i'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Sorry Take a look at https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview

Comment: are you having multiple menu icons and clicking on 1 expands all others?

Comment: @Aravind No i'm just trying to figure out how to expand/collapse a single menu at this stage

Comment: @Aravind I added my code and errors.

Comment: which version are you using! document says `<md-menu>` your code is using `<mat-menu>`

Comment: @Aravind Look at the link to the documentation I posted in a previous comment.  Everything there is mat-* i'm using angular2-material if that is what caused the confusion.  Every tag in ng2-material is mat-*

Comment: I referred to your link only.. Please have a look

Comment: Your code is correct, you don't need to write `matMenuTriggerFor` directive, it is part of the API, make sure you have imported the `MatMenuModule`, `MatButtonModule`, and `MatIconModule` into your app module.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/hv5i9Msx64fxnbUTZ6rp

Comment: @William Lohan please add that as the answer.  Can't believe I wasted 50 reputation points for missing a simple import:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Your code is correct, you don't need to write matMenuTriggerFor directive, it is part of the API, make sure you have imported the MatMenuModule, MatButtonModule, and MatIconModule into your app module." - from comments

Answer (score 6):

There is confusion because Material introduced a breaking change as I understand it..  See [material 2 Changelog - Breaking Changes](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes)

Starting with Material 2.0.0-beta.12.  Use `mat` instead of `md-*`..  Seems only some of the docs at [material.angular.io](https://material.angular.io/components/categories) are updated with mat.  Specifically, if you click view source and see `md`, I believe they have yet to replace it with `mat`.

So either update to Material 2.0.0-beta.12 and use `mat-*`, or use `md-*`.